# Adding field to Laravel migration schema

Tags: migration, laravel-5

I have read Laravel's documentation and other forums but it just doesn't work on me.  I have successfully migrated a table, now I wanted add a field, changed the schema to 'table' but all I get is 'Nothing to migrate'.

Here is what I've done.

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product', function(Blueprint $table)
        {

            $table->text('image');
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('dimension');
            $table->integer('ordered');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('product');
    }

}
```

Then, run the command `php artisan migrate`, and all is well.

Then I decided to add new field, so I changed the controller to this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('product', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('image'); //new
            $table->int('active'); //new
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->integer('amount');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('dimension');
            $table->integer('ordered');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('product');
    }

}
```

then run `php artisan migrate` again but I only get `Nothing to migrate`.

I also removed `Blueprint`, that didn't work as well. `migrate:refresh` and `migrate:reset` does the job but that is not what I want as it also removes the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do, follow these steps in order

`php artisan make:migration create_products_table`

Flesh out the up and down methods in your `create_products_table.php` (*Note:* the migration file will be preceded with a timestamp this will determine the order of the execution of the migrations when you run `php artisan migrate`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->string('dimension');
        $table->integer('ordered');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('product');
}
```

Then to create your table run `php artisan migrate`

So now you have your products table created, but now you want to *alter* the table and add some extra fields to it. Do this:

`php artisan make:migration alter_products_table_add_image_active`

Now you have a separate migration to alter the table, you don't want to edit the existing one, this is not how migrations work. They essentially keep a history of how the database is built, so any adjustments should be put into a new migration so if you happen to roll back you can revert back to a previous state which is accomplished by using the down method which is pretty much the opposite of the down method.

Now flesh out your up and down methods in your *alter* migration, `alter_products_table_add_image_active.php` (*Note:* remember the file would be automatically preceded with a timestamp)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('product', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->text('image');
        $table->int('active');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    // here you're not dropping the whole table, only removing the newly added columns
    Schema::table('club', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropColumn('image');
        $table->dropColumn('active');
    });
}
```

And this should get you up and running! Please let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Ahhh! nice one!  but have to change `$table->int('active');` to `$table->integer('active');`.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. I'll update my answer shortly didn't spot that thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

when we want modify table, we can use --table in migrate command, sample in menu table migrate for example

```
php artisan make:migrate [your migrate name] --table=menus
```